# Rspec testing for mailers and jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer, rspec-rails

**I have user model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_one :cart

  after_create :welcome_send
  def welcome_send
    SendEmailJob.perform_later(self)
  end
end
```

**This is the job**

```
class SendEmailJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(user)
    # Do something later
    @user = user
    # WelcomeMailer.send_welcome_email(@user).deliver_later(wait: 2.minute)
    WelcomeMailer.welcome_send(@user).deliver_later(wait: 2.minute)
  end
end
```

**This is the mailer**

```
class WelcomeMailer < ApplicationMailer
    def welcome_send(user)
        @user = user
        mail to: user.email, subject: 'Welcome to my site', from: 'suhasmv29@gmail.com'
    end
end
```

**The test case I have written for user model**

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do

  subject { User.create }

  it 'sends an email' do
    expect { subject.welcome_send(User.first) }
      .to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)

  end
end
```

**I am getting an error as wrong number of arguments**
Could anyone help. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `welcome_send` on `subject`.

In your example `subject` will be user's instance and user have `welcome_send` method which doesn't accept any parameter.

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do

  subject { User.create }

  it 'sends an email' do
    expect { subject }
      .to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
  end
end
```